# Approaches for Unit Testing Metastorm BPM

Tags: unit-testing, business-process-management

Has anyone been able to run automated unit (or even integration) tests on Metastorm BPM v9 and if so what approach did you take and tools did you use as a testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be quite tricky.

Also, will probably depend on what you want to test, output of certain classes, or certain BPM states.  OR do you want to test the BPM product by create Selenium type of recordings of the process and user activity.

To what component do you wanna apply a testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

For automated unit testing its probably best to use the ECL or web Services, and create a .NET project in order to perform the calls to the engine, measure and verify results.

If you would want to contain your tests in the Metastorm environment, then building processes that perform the testing via flag, ECL and Web services is also an option.

Another possibility is to use browser based automation tools, however getting these tools properly configured and working reliably can be a headache.